# ETW Manifest files - finding more information on the values?

Tags: tcp, etw, system.net, system.net.sockets, perfview

I'm troubleshooting the windows Networking stack and using Perfview/ETW to do it.

I'm particularly interested in some values that appear in the manifest for the event source Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP.

I can get the manifest with no problem using [this method](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/blob/e2e8b4400f2726d0143db4c49a0f92ae7c250485/documentation/TraceEvent/TraceEventProgrammersGuide.md#creating-xml-manifests-for-eventsource-sources)

```
PerfView /onlyProviders=*Microsoft-Demos-MySource EventSource collect

PerfView /noGui userCommand DumpEventSourceManifests PerfVIewData.etl.zip
```

The problem is that once i get the manifest, it has a bunch of values with not much explanation.

e.g.

```
 <template tid="TcpTemplateChangedArgs">
  <data name="Tcb" inType="win:Pointer"/>
  <data name="TemplateType" inType="win:UInt32"/>
  <data name="Context" inType="win:UnicodeString"/>
 </template>
```

where i'm specifically interested in this Context value, as in my test case i get "Initializing Templace SYNTCB" but that's it

I'd really like to know e.g.

- at what point in the stack/code this template change is fired
- what is this SYNTCB template anyway
- which microsoft team manages this particular ETW source so that maybe i can ask them a question somehow..

I've done my best to have a look around in the [.net codebase for system.net](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html) (networking code) to see if maybe there are ETW hooks in there but i cant find anything...

I can also see the event in Perfview, but cant find memory stack that holds the event (yep i've expanded all the system level events, and downloaded as many of the symbol libraries as possible)

Comment: You may try contacting the Message Analyzer team: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/messageanalyzer/. I'm sure they are using this provider in their tracing. Reversing the Message Analyzer binaries (most of them are managed) might also reveal something.

Comment: awesome thanks i'll give them a try!!